# how to set keyboard tab selection to a particular control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-events

I have two text boxes and two buttons...I had written some logic in first text box Lost Focus event.As soon as i click the keyboard tab  cursor will blink at second text box..Now i want to select the button 1 or button 2 instead of second text box.How can i achieve this...any idea...suggestion.

I added at the end of first text box LostFocus event

```
  Keyboard.Focus(btnName);

 FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, btnName);
```

these two didn't work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Use:

```
<TextBox KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0" />
<Button x:Name="btnName" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
```

Now you should be able to jump to the Button instead of the TextBox.

Comment: how can i set the KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" from code instead of xaml

Comment: You could maybe make a binding to a ViewModel or to code-behind to set that value.
<Button x:Name="btnName" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="{Binding TabIndex}" />